# How to route 0.0.0.0:22 to 192.168.122.179:22?

Tags: ssh, tcp, port-forwarding

I want to route 0.0.0.0:22 to 192.168.122.179:22 which is a VM. This way I can access my VM through SSH by typinh the local IP of the host machine. However i get connection refused if I try to ssh from host to vm, or even (obviously) from local machine to host to vm,

```
root@z:/home/lz# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d 0.0.0.0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j  DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.179:22
root@z:/home/lz# iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0              tcp dpt:22 to:192.168.122.179:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1161 89206 LIBVIRT_PRT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain LIBVIRT_PRT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    5   340 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24        
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255     
   39  2340 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    6   456 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0:22` is an invalid IPv4 address that cannot be used as a destination address.

Comment: @RonMaupin I thougth it meant the source address. How can I bind the port 22 of 0.0.0.0 (that is, bind the host port 22) to 192.168.122.179:22?

Comment: @RonMaupin if it says `--to-destination 192.168.122.179:22` then the other address should be the source, isn't it?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` can only be used as a source address for a host requesting an IPv4 address. Your use of port 22 means that you want to use SSH, which is a bidirectional protocol, so any responses will need to be sent to `0.0.0.0`, which cannot be a destination address.

Comment: @RonMaupin understood. How can I do it then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124777